# Empty RecyclerView using fetched Data from parse.com

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform, android-recyclerview

I am currently struggling to implement data `fetching` from a `class` i created on `parse.com`. I wanted to retrieve an object which is entitled **"flyerDataFetch**" and all of its elements to display within a `Recyclerview`.

When I run and compile the program I receive the errors:

```
error:java.lang.NullPointerException at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:211) 
Error: RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout.
```

*Can you please review my code and help identify where I went wrong in the process of trying to populate my `RecyclerView`?*

`MainActivity`:

```
public class HomeScreen extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerDrawer;
    private customAdapter mAdapter;
    private Context context;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
        setupDrawer();
        final List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
        ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("flyerDataFetch");
        query.getInBackground("xWMyZ4YEGZ", new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseObject parseObject, com.parse.ParseException e) {
                if (e == null) {

                    Information information = new Information();
                    information.partyName = parseObject.getString("partyName");
                    information.partyPromoterName = parseObject.getString("partyCost");
                    information.partyCost = parseObject.getString("partyName");

                    information.flyerPic = parseObject.getParseFile("partyFlyerImage");
                    information.partyPromoterPic = parseObject.getParseFile("partyPromoterImage");

                    data.add(information);
                } else {
                    // something went wrong
                }
                mRecyclerDrawer = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
                mRecyclerDrawer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
                mAdapter = new customAdapter(context, data);
                mRecyclerDrawer.setAdapter(mAdapter);
            }
        });

    }
```

`MyApplication`:

```
 @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        sInstance = this;
        ParseCrashReporting.enable(this);
        Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    }
```

`CustomAdapter`:

```
package com.example.jbobo_000.prac;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.parse.ParseImageView;

import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class customAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<customAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    List<Information> data = Collections.emptyList();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;
    public customAdapter (Context context,List<Information>data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data= data;
    }

   @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType){
       View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
       MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
       return holder;
   }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder,int position){
        Information current= data.get(position);
        holder.promoterNameText.setText(current.partyPromoterName);
        holder.costText.setText(current.partyCost);
        holder.partyNameText.setText(current.partyName);
        holder.flyerImage.setParseFile(current.flyerPic);
        holder.promoterImage.setParseFile(current.partyPromoterPic);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount(){

        return data.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        TextView promoterNameText;
        TextView costText;
        TextView partyNameText;
        ParseImageView flyerImage;
        ParseImageView promoterImage;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            promoterImage = (ParseImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.promoterPicImage);
            flyerImage = (ParseImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.flyertImage);
            costText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.costText);
            promoterNameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.promoterNameText);
            partyNameText = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.partyNameText);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            context.startActivity(new Intent(context, partyInformation.class));

        }
    }
}
```

`Information`:

```
package com.example.jbobo_000.prac;
import com.parse.ParseFile;
import com.parse.ParseImageView;

public class Information {
    public ParseFile flyerPic;
    public ParseFile partyPromoterPic;
    public String partyCost;
    public String partyName;
    public String partyPromoterName;



}
```

`Logcat`:

```
06-12 01:52:37.511    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac E/RecyclerView﹕ No adapter attached; skipping layout
06-12 01:52:37.766    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
06-12 01:52:37.766    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac E/CrashReporting﹕ ParseCrashReporting caught a NullPointerException exception for com.example.jbobo_000.prac. Building report.
06-12 01:52:37.768    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac E/CrashReporting﹕ Handling exception for crash
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:219)
            at com.example.jbobo_000.prac.customAdapter.<init>(customAdapter.java:25)
            at com.example.jbobo_000.prac.HomeScreen$1.done(HomeScreen.java:57)
            at com.example.jbobo_000.prac.HomeScreen$1.done(HomeScreen.java:38)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-12 01:52:37.768    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ Generating report file for crash
06-12 01:52:37.843    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ Retrieving logcat output...
06-12 01:52:37.871    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ Retrieving logcat output...
06-12 01:52:37.889    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ Retrieving logcat output...
06-12 01:52:37.965    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac W/Settings﹕ Setting stay_on_always has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.
06-12 01:52:38.164    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac V/CrashReporting﹕ About to start ReportSenderWorker from #handleException
06-12 01:52:38.172    5432-5603/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ #checkAndSendReports - start
06-12 01:52:38.172    5432-5603/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ Looking for error files in /data/data/com.example.jbobo_000.prac/files/com.parse/cr/reports
06-12 01:52:38.175    5432-5603/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ Loading file 1434088357768-NullPointerException-1.stacktrace
06-12 01:52:38.185    5432-5603/com.example.jbobo_000.prac I/CrashReporting﹕ Sending file 1434088357768-NullPointerException-1.stacktrace
06-12 01:52:38.186    5432-5603/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ Sending crash report to Parse...
06-12 01:52:38.193    5432-5603/com.example.jbobo_000.prac D/CrashReporting﹕ #checkAndSendReports - finish
06-12 01:52:38.265    5432-5432/com.example.jbobo_000.prac E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.jbobo_000.prac, PID: 5432
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object android.content.Context.getSystemService(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:219)
            at com.example.jbobo_000.prac.customAdapter.<init>(customAdapter.java:25)
            at com.example.jbobo_000.prac.HomeScreen$1.done(HomeScreen.java:57)
            at com.example.jbobo_000.prac.HomeScreen$1.done(HomeScreen.java:38)
            at com.parse.ParseTaskUtils$2$1.run(ParseTaskUtils.java:107)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
06-12 01:52:38.291    5432-5442/com.example.jbobo_000.prac W/art﹕ Suspending all threads took: 5.494ms
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here are the all things you should change.. first you are not getting all data of table(Object) flyerDataFetch, you are just getting the one specific column data with id "xWMyZ4YEGZ" your query should be

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("flyerDataFetch");
    query.findInBackgroud(new FindCallBack<TableClass>(){


        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject List<TableName> list, com.parse.ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

       // GENERATE LOOP HERE AND GET ALL DATA OF LIST INTO YOUR LOCAL LIST WHICH YOU ARE PASSING TO ADAPTER OF RECYCLER VIEW
      //I am telling you to add loop so you can learn.. 
                Information information = new Information();
                information.partyName = parseObject.getString("partyName");
                information.partyPromoterName = parseObject.getString("partyCost");
                information.partyCost = parseObject.getString("partyName");

                information.flyerPic = parseObject.getParseFile("partyFlyerImage");
                information.partyPromoterPic = parseObject.getParseFile("partyPromoterImage");

                data.add(information);
            } else {
                // something went wrong
            }
```

this will get all the data from table and set in your List which you are passing to adapter. this could be the reason of your NullPointerException!

other thing is the way you are getting image is wrong 
you actually need perform query and get the bytes[] array and then you can set up in the ParseImageView

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data, 0, data.length, options);
myViewHolder.myImageView.setBitmapImage(bmp);
```

also you don't need context in your customAdapter .. simply write this

```
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public customAdapter (Context context,List<Information>data){
    inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    this.data= data;
}
```

also In your MainActivity class..change this

```
 mRecyclerDrawer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context));
mAdapter = new customAdapter(context, data);
```

to

```
  mRecyclerDrawer.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
mAdapter = new customAdapter(getApplicationContext(), data);
```

.. declare your following data

```
final List<Information> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

in your MainActivity before onCreate() method..

hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback! I will implement your corrections!

Comment: i updated.. make changes .. for now to get the text properly just implement the necessary changes, you can query about image later.. let me know if still getting any problems ..

Comment: I figured it out and now the recyclerview is populated with your help. Thanks! Do you mind going into detail on how i can populate my two imageviews?

Comment: i have given you most important thing you need to do in imagequery.. n then place in to myViewHolder .. just need to get data from parse in bytes[] and then convert it into bitmap as i told you in answer...

Answer (score 2):

context is null .Please set context value to the activity before you call the adapter.
Add

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_screen);
context=this;
```